# Diferencia entre Runnable, Handler, Thread

Tags: java, android

¿Cúal es la diferencia entre Runnable, Handler, Thread?

También tenemos el AsynkTask, algunas veces los utilizamos para ciertas cosas, ¿pero debemos utilizar cada uno en casos especificos ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Handler**

Un Handler está hecho en Java (internamente usa un Thread), por lo que todo lo que puede hacer con Handler, se puede lograr con un hilo también.

Entonces, ¿por qué usar Handler? La razón es como abajo:

- Handler permite enviar y procesar objetos Message y Runnable asociados con MessageQueue de un thread. Para decirlo en términos simples, el manejador facilita su trabajo.
- Android tiene dos reglas principales para el manejo de los hilos:

  - No bloquee el hilo de la interfaz de usuario
  - No accedas al kit de herramientas de la interfaz de usuario de Android desde fuera del hilo de la interfaz de usuario

Para enlazar por las 2 reglas indicadas anteriormente, en android tenemos 3 métodos integrados que pueden manejar la situación cuando una de sus clases de actividad se ejecutan o se llaman desde un hilo diferente.

A continuación, podemos programar las actualizaciones de la interfaz de usuario para que se ejecuten en el subproceso de interfaz de usuario con estos tres métodos a continuación. La actividad o vista funciona como manejador (más información sobre los manejadores a continuación) y programa su ejecución al subproceso de la interfaz de usuario:

- Activity.runOnUiThread (Runnable)

  - View.post (Runnable)
  - View.postDelayed (Runnable, long) // (largo = tiempo hasta la programación)

Permite enviar mensajes entre dos subprocesos de una manera segura, esto significa que el hilo de envío pone el mensaje en la cola de subprocesos de destino y esta cola de destino procesará este mensaje en su momento apropiado.

**Runnable**

Runnable es sólo una interfaz que necesita para instanciar un hilo para contenerlo. Mientras que el hilo contiene ya la capacidad de generar un hilo. Si usted extiende el hilo usted no puede extender cualquier cosa (Java no admite la herencia múltiple). Puede tener múltiples interfaces en una clase, por lo tanto podría tener Runnable.

Además, cuando extiende la clase Thread, cada subproceso crea un objeto único y se asocia con él. Cuando implementa Runnable, comparte el mismo objeto con varios subprocesos.

Esta es una interfaz que implementar, en la implementación de poner la lógica que desea ejecutar en algún hilo. También puede utilizar Runnable en lugares no relacionados con hilos. Un montón de Java apis en realidad utilizan Runnable, no sólo Thread's. Puede publicar Runnable utilizando el controlador, o puede utilizarlo con los ejecutores. Los runnables son buenos porque puedes implementarlos en una forma de implementación anónima.

**Thread**

Un `Thread` es un hilo de ejecución en un programa. La máquina virtual de Java permite que una aplicación tenga varios subprocesos de ejecución ejecutándose simultáneamente.

Cada subproceso tiene una prioridad. Los hilos con mayor prioridad se ejecutan de preferencia a los hilos con menor prioridad. Cada subproceso puede o no estar marcado como un daemon. Cuando el código que se ejecuta en algún subproceso crea un nuevo objeto Thread, el nuevo subproceso tiene su prioridad inicialmente establecida igual a la prioridad del subproceso de creación y es un subproceso de daemon si y sólo si el subproceso de creación es un daemon.

Cuando se inicia una máquina virtual Java, suele haber un único subproceso no daemon (que normalmente llama al método denominado `main` de alguna clase designada). La máquina virtual Java continúa ejecutando los subprocesos hasta que se produzca alguna de las siguientes situaciones:

- Se ha llamado al método `exit` de la clase `Runtime` y el gestor de seguridad ha permitido que se lleve a cabo la operación de salida.
- Todos los hilos que no son hilos de daemon han muerto, ya sea volviendo de la llamada al método run o lanzando una excepción que se propaga más allá del método `run`.

Un Thread tiene un estado al que el runnable probablemente no necesita acceder. Tener acceso a más estados de lo necesario es un diseño deficiente.

Los hilos ocupan mucha memoria. Crear un nuevo subproceso para cada pequeña acción requiere tiempo de procesamiento para asignar y desasignar esta memoria.

**UIThread**

La mayoría de las interfaces de usuario implementan sus trabajos en un solo hilo, todos los elementos de la interfaz de usuario: las ventanas / widgets se comunican mediante mensajes (al igual que en Handler). Es decir. El usuario presiona el botón, éste inicia un mensaje con la información que el botón fue presionado, él es envía al hilo de la interfaz de usuario y finalmente entregado a su oyente.

En Android está prohibido modificar los elementos de la interfaz de usuario desde un subproceso no UI, esto tiene sentido. Si lo modificas desde otro subproceso, esto podría suceder mientras el subproceso de la interfaz de usuario está realizando algunos cambios en el mismo widget. .
Google Traductor para empresas:Translator ToolkitTraductor de sitios webGlobal Market Finder
Acerca de Google TraductorComunidadCelulares
Acerca de GooglePrivacidad y condicionesAyudaEnviar comentarios

**AsyncTask**

AsyncTask permite el uso adecuado y sencillo del subproceso de interfaz de usuario. Esta clase le permite realizar operaciones en segundo plano y publicar resultados en el subproceso de interfaz de usuario sin tener que manipular subprocesos y / o controladores.

AsyncTask está diseñado para ser una clase auxiliar en torno a Thread y Handler y no constituye un marco de subprocesamiento genérico. AsyncTasks idealmente debe ser utilizado para operaciones cortas (unos pocos segundos a lo sumo). Si necesita mantener los threads en ejecución durante largos períodos de tiempo, se recomienda utilizar las distintas API proporcionadas por el paquete java.util.concurrent tales como Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor y FutureTask.

Una tarea asincrónica se define mediante un cálculo que se ejecuta en un subproceso de fondo y cuyo resultado se publica en el subproceso de interfaz de usuario. Una tarea asincrónica está definida por 3 tipos genéricos, denominados Params, Progress y Result, y 4 pasos, llamados onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate y onPostExecute.

### Como posibilidad, podemos elegir alguno respecto a otro:

- Utilizar **AsyncTask** si se necesita ejecutar una tarea corta comunicándose con el subproceso de la interfaz de usuario
- Utilizar un **Thread** y **Handler** para ejecutar tareas más largas que requieran comunicación entre el hilo de trabajo y el hilo principal (hilo de llamada)
- Usar **Thread**, **Handler** y **Looper** (o **HandlerThread**, que es una clase para iniciar un subproceso que ya tiene un Looper) para tareas más largas que requieren comunicación entre el subproceso de trabajo Y el hilo de la persona que llama (no el hilo principal).
- Utilizar **IntentService** para una tarea más larga que no requiere la interacción del usuario y sólo necesita un subproceso de trabajo.

Referencias obligadas:

- [AsyncTask, Handler, Thread… Which one to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23772171/4987172)
- [Handler vs AsyncTask vs Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread)
- [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

Answer (score 7):

Son definiciones que tienen cosas en común pero decidí agruparlos para explicar mejor, agrego la definición de la documentación oficial y una propia:

**Thread y Handler**:

**[Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)**

> Un **Thread** es un hilo de ejecución en un programa. La máquina
>   virtual de Java permite que una aplicación tenga varios Threads de
>   ejecución ejecutándose simultáneamente.
>
> Cada Thread tiene una prioridad. Los hilos con mayor prioridad se
>   ejecutan de preferencia a los hilos con menor prioridad. Cada
>   Thread puede o no estar marcado como un daemon. Cuando el código
>   que se ejecuta en algún Thread crea un nuevo objeto Thread, el
>   nuevo Thread tiene su prioridad inicialmente establecida igual a
>   la prioridad del Thread de creación y es un Thread de daemon
>   si y sólo si el Thread de creación es un daemon.

**Un [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) se encarga de crear un proceso en segundo plano. La cantidad posible de Threads permitida es a discreción del usuario. El problema principal que encontramos con un Thread es que no podemos modificar datos en el hilo principal de la aplicación.**

Ejemplo:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Aquí agregamos el proceso a ejecutar.
    }
}).start();
```

**[Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)**

> Un **[Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)** le permite enviar y procesar objetos Message y Runnable
>   asociados con MessageQueue de un Thread. Cada instancia de Handler
>   está asociada con un solo Thread y la cola de mensajes de dicho
>   Thread. Cuando se crea un nuevo Handler, está enlazado a la fila /
>   cola de mensajes del Thread que lo está creando. A partir de ese
>   punto, se entregarán mensajes y ejecutables (Runnables) a esa cola de mensajes y
>   los ejecutará a medida que salgan del mensaje cola.

**A diferencia de un Thread, el Handler puede realizar modificaciones en nuestro hilo principal. Prodría decirse que un [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) es el puente que hay entre un hilo secundario y hilo principal.**

**¿Cuando usar un Handler en lugar de un thread? Cuando requiramos realizar operaciones en el Hilo principal.**

Ejemplo:

```
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Aquí agregamos el proceso a ejecutar.           
        };
    });
```

---

**Interfaz Runable:**

**[Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html)**

> La interfaz [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) debe ser implementada por cualquier clase
>   cuyas instancias estén destinadas a ser ejecutadas por un Thread.
>   La clase debe definir un método sin argumentos llamado run.
>
> Esta interfaz está diseñada para proporcionar un protocolo común para
>   objetos que desean ejecutar código mientras están activos. Por
>   ejemplo, Runnable se implementa por clase Thread. Ser activo significa
>   simplemente que un hilo se ha iniciado y aún no ha sido detenido.

**[Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html)**
**[Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) es una interfaz que es necesaria para instanciar un Thread (Hilo), El Thread ya tiene la capacidad de generar un hilo pero si deseamos que una clase sea ejecutada en un Thread debemos implementar esta interface.**

---

**Asynctask y runOnUIThread:**

**[runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))**

> Ejecuta la acción especificada en el hilo principal (UI Thread). Si el
>   actual Thread no es el hilo principal (UI Thread), la acción se
>   ejecuta inmediatamente. Si el Thread actual no es el Thread de
>   UI, la acción se contabiliza en la cola de sucesos del Thread de
>   UI.

**El cuando necesitamos realizar una operación en el Hilo principal desde un hilo que no es el principal.**

Ejemplo:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Aquí agregamos el proceso a ejecutar en el UI Thread.
    }
});
```

Aquí viene la pregunta pregunta importante: **¿para que usar [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) si podemos usar un [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)?**

Bueno, ambos pueden realizar operaciones en el hilo principal (UI Thread) pero  runOnUiThread() solo ejecuta un proceso desde un thread, y además se tiene que pasar una referencia de la activity en la cual se ejecuta.

En cuanto al Handler es que se pueden encolar procesos que se ejecutarían en una hilo diferente al propio,
incluso se pueden programar mensajes y ejecutables para realizarse en un tiempo determinado.

Ejemplo:

**¿Cómo hacer que una función se ejecute cada n segundos?**

```
    //Este handler será ejecutado 5 segundos después.  
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

          //***Aquí agregamos el proceso a ejecutar.

          Log.i(TAG, "Ejecuta postDelayed");
        };
    }, 5000); //Cada 5 segundos, 5000 milisegundos.
```

**[AsynkTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**

> [AsynkTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) permite el uso adecuado y sencillo del hilo principal (UI > Thread). Esta clase le permite realizar operaciones en
>   segundo plano y publica los resultados en el hilo principal (UI Thread)
>   sin tener que usar Threads o Handlers.
>
> AsyncTask está diseñado para ser una clase auxiliar en torno a Thread
>   y Handler y no constituye un Threading Framework.
>   AsyncTasks idealmente debe ser utilizado para operaciones cortas (unos
>   pocos segundos a lo máximo). Si necesita mantener los threads en
>   ejecución durante largos períodos de tiempo, se recomienda utilizar
>   las distintas API proporcionadas por el paquete java.util.concurrent
>   tales como Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor y FutureTask.

**La ventaja que nos proporciona un AsyncTask con respecto a un runOnUiThread() es que con el Asynctask podemos administrar varias tareas y que no tenemos necesidad de crear varios  runOnUiThread().**