# Atascado tratando de implementar un Thread y Handler, Varias dudas

Tags: java, android, hilos

Qué tal.

Estoy empezando a aprender sobre las tareas ejecutadas en segundo plano.

El siguiente ejercicio lo pude ejecutar con Asyntask (aun tengo dudas de cómo lo implemente), pero esta funcionando bien. Dado que Asyntask esta etiquetado como "descontinuado", estoy tratando de hacer la misma tarea con Thread y Handler, pero estoy atorado desde hace 2 semanas.

El codigo es el siguiente (resumido):

```
public class ConversorUsoDLL extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


ProgressDialog progressD01; 
Button btnEjecutar;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    btnEjecutar = findViewById(Integer.parseInt("302"));
    
}

 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 
 int id = view.getId();
 
 if (id == 302)     //Buttons Ejecutar.
        {
            testConversor07()
        }
        
}


public String testConversor05(){
    
    int i,j;
    String Resultado="";

        for(j=0; j<sppUnidadIn.getCount(); j++) {
                          
                    Resultado = Resultado +
                            "Inicio de Seccion. <BR> " +
                            "$ Magnitud: " + nameMagnitud + "<BR> " +
                            "$ UnidadIn: " + sppUnidadIn.getItemAtPosition(j).toString() + "<BR> " +
                            "$ Valor: " + edtxtValor.getText().toString() + "<BR>";

                    
                        Valor1Lay01 = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(edtxtValor.getText()));
                    
                    
                    for (i = 0; i < sppUnidadOut.getCount(); i++) {

                        if (!sppUnidadOut.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().contains("------")) { 
                            Resultado = Resultado +
                                    "-- " + sppUnidadOut.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "  ->  " +
                                    DLLConversorGMM.Conversor(
                                            Valor1Lay01,
                                            Valor1Lay01.toString(), 
                                            nameMagnitud,
                                            sppUnidadIn.getItemAtPosition(j).toString(),
                                            sppUnidadOut.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(),
                                            context
                                    ) + 
                                    "<BR>";
                        }
                    }

              
                Resultado = Resultado + "Fin de Seccion. <BR> <BR>";

           

        }//fin de Ciclo de unidad 01.


   

    return Resultado;

}//fin de testConversor05


public void testConversor07(){
              
        progressD01 = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressD01.setMax(100);
        progressD01.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressD01.show();

        Thread hilo1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                testConversor05()
            }
        });
        hilo1.start();


        //{DLLToolsGMM.mostrarAlertHTML2Btns(context ,"Modo Programador Activado.\nTarea Asincrona.", Resultado,"Cont.","Cont.");}


}//fin de testConversor7()

}
```

Una vez que el botón Ejecutar es presionado, se activa el método testConversor07().

El objetivo de testConversor07() es correr la tarea de alto consumo testConversor05() en segundo plano.

Atorado con:

Cómo envío el porcentanje de avance hacia un progressDialog denominado como "progressD01", durante la ejecución de testConversor05()?.

Cómo obtengo en valor de la variable "Resultado" que retorna el método testConversor05() cuando concluye la ejecución Thread en testConversor07(), para poder utilizarlo?.

De verdad apreciaría muchísimo su apoyo en desatorar mis dudas.

Saludos.

gerardo2m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya entiendo el porque, el problema está a la hora de llamar al método getResult(), como este método está en el hilo principal de ejecución no es accesible desde la clase Thread, en cambio debes usar la clase Handler, ya que esta clase permite la comunicación con el hilo principal. Solo debes cambiar Thread por Handler.

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler();
handler1.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        testConversor5();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día gerardo2m, para enviar un porcentaje de avance del progress dialog puedes utilizar el ciclo for e ir incementando el porcentaje con cada iteración:

```
double progress = (double) j / sppUnidadIn.getCount() * 100;
progressD01.setProgress((int) progress);
```

Para utilizar el la variable resultado devuelta por el método testConversor05() puedes llamar a un método antes de la sentencia return. Por ejemplo:

```
{
    //ciclo for
    //...
    //fin del ciclo for

    getResult(Resultado);
    return Resultado;
    //Fin del método testConversor05()
}

private void getResult (String resultado){
    //trabajas con la variable resultado
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, para más información puedes revisar [Diferencia entre Runnable, Handler, Thread](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38201/diferencia-entre-runnable-handler-thread)

Comment: Que tal Ariel. Gracias por tu interés en ayudarme.  Las lineas para que se visualizara el avance en el ProgressDialog funcionaron muy bien. Pero no se logró poder utilizar la variable de retorno "Resultado". En el método getResult, coloqué un Toast que indicara el valor de "Resultado"; pero el Toast no se activo ni se indicó error, pareciera que el programa no llega a getResult.