# Pasar de Activity en un Thread tras respuesta de Servidor

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo una activity que hace un POST a un WebService. Esto se hace correctamente y obtengo en la activty el "1" del servidor que indica que la consulta se efectuó correctamente. He puesto un if para que muestre un Toast con el resultado y de paso que haga un Intent para cambiar de Activity, pero no lanza el Intent.

Os dejo el código:

```
public class NuevoAvaInf extends Activity {

    EditText veh,apar,notas;
    private Plan miPlan;

    private int exito=-1;

    Toast toast1;
    Intent passIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_ava_inf);

        miPlan = new Plan();
        miPlan = (Plan)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miPlan");

        veh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAutos);
        apar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPark);
        notas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNotas);

        ImageButton siguiente = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.siguiente);

        siguiente.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                miPlan.setVehiclos(veh.getText().toString());
                miPlan.setAparcamiento(apar.getText().toString());
                miPlan.setInfo(notas.getText().toString());

                sendPost();
            }
        });

    }

    public void sendPost() {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://...");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String JSON = gson.toJson(miPlan);

                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");

                    osw.write(JSON.toString());
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();


                    Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                    Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());

                    StringBuffer response = null;

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

Log.i("RESPUESTA" , response.toString().trim());

                    if(response.toString().trim().equals("1"))
                    {
                        exito=1;
                        Log.i("Exito Despues" , String.valueOf(exito));

                        toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tu Plan se ha guardado con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast1.show();

                        passIntent = new Intent();
                        passIntent.setClass(NuevoAvaInf.this, Menu.class);
                        startActivity(passIntent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha ocurrido un ERROR.\nTu plan NO se ha guardado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast1.show();
                    }

                    conn.disconnect();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }


}
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Se muestra algún error en el LogCat? me parece que se esta generando un error del tipo IllegalStateException

Comment: No, creo que es que hay que usar AsynTask para poder manejar la Activity principal desde el hilo que hace el POST al servidor. Estoy probándolo ahora mismo. Si funciona os digo y dejo el código para que alguien lo reutilice

Comment: Exacto , esa es la razón por la cual no se abre la Activity, agregué un ejemplo usando un AsyncTask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que desde un hilo no puedes ejecutar acciones relacionadas a la interfaz gráfica de manera directa. Ya que no se controla cuando termina el hilo por su propiedad asíncrona.

Para esto hay que poner el cola la respuesta de mensajes dentro del hilo para que cuando este termine ejecute el mensaje hacia la interfaz.

Para esto utilizamos la clase `Handler` y con le método `post` podemos integrar la comunicación con la interfaz. [Aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) puedes leer mas sobre el tema.

en tu caso para resolver el problema sería:

```
public void sendPost() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 

        // ... tu codígo para esperar la repuesta del ws

        in.close();
        Log.i("RESPUESTA" , response.toString().trim());
        conn.disconnect();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            if(response.toString().trim().equals("1"))
            {
                exito=1;
                Log.i("Exito Despues" , String.valueOf(exito));

                toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tu Plan se ha guardado con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast1.show();

                passIntent = new Intent();
                passIntent.setClass(NuevoAvaInf.this, Menu.class);
                startActivity(passIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha ocurrido un ERROR.\nTu plan NO se ha guardado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast1.show();
            }
        });
        ...
```

Comment: qué es mejor handler o asyntask?

Comment: como tal asyntask es mas sencillo de utilizar, pero en la API 30 ya es una librería depreciada por lo que se recomienda usar otra forma de control de rutinas asíncronas

Answer (score 3):

En este caso puedes usar un [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) o también puedes usar un `Handler`

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        passIntent = new Intent();
        passIntent.setClass(NuevoAvaInf.this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(passIntent);
    }
};
```

Este es un ejemplo usando un [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask):

```
    class AsyncTaskPOST extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://............................");
            } catch (MalformedURLException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                //Outputstream para enviar datos (json)
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                //el json lo convertimos a String
                writer.write(params[0].toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String inputStr;
                while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                    responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

                String data = responseStrBuilder.toString();
                streamReader.close();

                //Crea un json de la respuesta recibida
                JSONObject json = null;
                try {
                    json = new JSONObject(data);
                    return json;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject s) {
            if (s != null)
                try {
                    Log.d("Response", s.getString("response"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ocurrio un error, por favor intenta de nuevo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Revisa otras opciones:

[Diferencia entre Runnable, Handler, Thread](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/38222/95)

Comment: viendo el enlace que me has dejado me decanto por Asyntask ya que es muy corta la tarea de consulta

Comment: @wiki para las peticiones lo mejor es usar un Asynctask, en doInBackground() realizas la petición y los cambios en la ui los realizas en onPostExecute(), edite mi respuesta agregando un ejemplo con AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2):

Dejo mi código con Asyntask, aunque parece ser que ya esta obsoleta a partir de la API 30..

```
public class NuevoAvaInf extends Activity {

    EditText veh,apar,notas;
    private Plan miPlan;

    private int exito=-1;
    private String json;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_ava_inf);

        miPlan = new Plan();
        miPlan = (Plan)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miPlan");

        veh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAutos);
        apar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPark);
        notas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNotas);

        ImageButton siguiente = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.siguiente);

        siguiente.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                miPlan.setVehiclos(veh.getText().toString());
                miPlan.setAparcamiento(apar.getText().toString());
                miPlan.setInfo(notas.getText().toString());

            

                json="";
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                json = gson.toJson(miPlan);

                peticionAsync();
            }
        });

    }

    public void peticionAsync()
    {
        PeticionAsync pA = new PeticionAsync();
        pA.execute(myURL);
    }
    class PeticionAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            return POST("myURL");
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            Log.i("RESULT: ","Consulta:"+result);

            if (result.trim().equals("1"))
            {
                Intent passIntent = new Intent();
                passIntent.setClass(NuevoAvaInf.this,Menu.class);
                startActivity(passIntent);
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Plan creado correcamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
            }

            else
            {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en la conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
            }
        }

        public String POST(String url) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            URL urlA;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            try {
                urlA = new URL(muURL);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            String data = json;
            String result = null;

            try
            {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlA.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.connect();

                OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(data);
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                String line = null; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```